# Action on multiple buttons - JQuery

Tags: jquery

I need to write a function that works on button1 & button2..which I click button1, Im able to hide t but how can I add the same function for button2?

```
<html>
    <head>

        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
        </script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $("#button1").click(function(){
                $(this).hide();
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button id="button1">Button1</button>
        <button id="button2">Button2</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add it to the selector :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#button1, #button2").click(function(){
        $(this).hide();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a class instead of using an id as an identifier, then apply your class to all elements you want to have the same action.

```
<button class="yourbuttons" id="button1">Button1</button>
<button class="yourbuttons" id="button2">Button2</button>
```

Then:

```
$(".yourbuttons").click(function(){
    $(this).hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your event handler already uses `this` to reference whichever element has triggered the event (i.e. in this case, has been clicked), you just need to generalise the selector you put into `$()` in order to include `#button2`. This'll depend upon your markup, but as it stands you could use:

```
$("#button1, #button2").click(function () {
    $(this).hide();
});
```

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BByTB/